# What is "view_permission" on portlet/configure.zcml for?

Tags: plone, plone-3.x

In `<browser:page />` on Plone, I have a `permission` attribute. I can add a custom permission in there and have better security when the browser view is rendered.

```
  <browser:page
      for="*"
      name="my_view"
      class=".myview.MyView"
      allowed_interface=".myview.IMyView"
      permission="my.permission"
      />
```

Just adding the `permission` attribute it works: trying to do @@my_view, it asks for login.

Now, let's go to the portlets: portlets have a `view_permission`, that I thought it [would do the same](http://www.packtpub.com/article/creating-customizing-and-assigning-portlets-automatically-plone-33), or at least just wouldn't render the portlet if the user didn't have the permission - but none of these situations happen. The portlet is rendered, ignoring the `view_permission`, thus I still need to use the [available portlet property](http://readthedocs.org/docs/collective-docs/en/latest/portlets/tips.html#available-property) to accomplish what I want (It seems I'm not the only one [doing this approach](https://weblion.psu.edu/trac/weblion/changeset?new=10080@studentClubs/multi/clubspace.clubwebmasters&old=9805@studentClubs/multi/clubspace.clubwebmasters)).

So, what `view_permission` is for? I can't find the docs for it. It seems I would be able to use it like `permission` like browser views, but it seems I can't...

Comment: I'm not sure in which context the view_permission is checked: on the context that the user is now viewing or on the context where the portlet is defined.  I'd guess the first.  Maybe that explains what you are seeing?  Just a hunch.

Comment: maurits, I was thinking exactly about that, but if it was the first, I would be seeing the portlet, not the other way round. I think `grep` is going to be my answer soon... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the purpose of view_permission *is* to restrict the portlet to users with a specific permission...as it says here:

http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.app.portlets/trunk/plone/app/portlets/metadirectives.py

here you can find an example:

http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.portlet.collection/trunk/plone/portlet/collection/configure.zcml

**edit**:
unfortunately I have to amend my answer...the purpose of view_permission *should be*  to restrict the portlet to users with a specific permission. But it's not yet honored, as you can see here:

- http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.app.portlets/trunk/plone/app/portlets/browser/templates/column.pt
- http://svn.plone.org/svn/plone/plone.app.portlets/trunk/plone/app/portlets/metaconfigure.py

(Thanks to the comment of Ulrich Schwarz that pushed me to double check.)

Comment: Is that permission actually obeyed now? Last time I checked (4.0.4 or so), you could trace the flow for view_permission up to a comment that said more-or-less "no, we don't".